# LookUp for two enum values

Tags: c#, dictionary, enums

[C#]
Hi,
What is the best solution to have something like a lookup or dict that would match an int key for two values represented by enums (i.e. something like `Dict<int, enum, enum>`)?
I need to take those two enums and find the assosiated int number for them.
I am looking for the best approach.
I found that maybe creation of new object would be to represent those two enums or use a Tuple there. I also found osmething like Lookup structure, but I still don't know what would be the best approach, cause I am a freshie

Comment: Could you provide *some examples*, some *code* to show what are going to achieve?

Comment: It's like a have one enum for a description and another one for some type.
What i want to achieve is to get the int value for specific description and type.
For example (for desc = "sth" and type = "xyz" I want to get the reflecting int id)

Comment: Use Enum.Parse() : Enum.Parse(typeof(Program), "Enum Name")

Comment: I answer below how to quickly get an int from an enum in C#, but you need to add a bit more detail as mentioned above if you want a more specific answer.

Answer (score 0):

If your enum is an int you can just cast as such

```
int enumNumber = (int) exampleenum.keyA;
```

so enumNumber would be cast as 1 for the below.

```
private enum exampleenum
{
    KeyA = 1,
    KeyB = 2,
    KeyC = 3,
    KeyD = 4
}
```

A dictionary can't have two values, it is a is key value pair (two). To use a dictionary with two values you will need to make a custom object for your two enums as.

I am not sure what over heads this would have performance wise you may want to look into using a Tuple instead.

Example object

```
class EnumObject
{
    public Enum Enum1 { get; set; }
    public Enum Enum2 { get; set; }
}
```

Populating the dictionary

```
        Dictionary<int, EnumObject> dic = new Dictionary<int, EnumObject>()
        {
            {1, new EnumObject() { Enum1 = exampleenum.KeyA, Enum2 = exampleenum.KeyB }},
            {2, new EnumObject() { Enum1 = exampleenum.KeyA, Enum2 = exampleenum.KeyC }},
            {3, new EnumObject() { Enum1 = exampleenum.KeyA, Enum2 = exampleenum.KeyD }}
        };
```

Then you can use linq to lookup the value and key the key.

```
        int Key = dic.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == new EnumObject() { Enum1 = exampleenum.KeyA, Enum2 = exampleenum.KeyB }).Key;
```

Comment: Hi Rick! it's not about getting the int key, but getting and int that would be a key for two values represented by enums. Something like Dict<int, enum1, enum2>

Comment: OK now, I understand you, you want the key (int) from a dictionary based on two enums, you should be able to do this with Linq

Comment: But you can't have two values in a dictionary, you will need to make a custom object for your two enums as. A dictionary is key value pair, three values would be a Tuple.

Comment: Yes exactly this is one of options I thought about beacuse of Dictionary "limitation". As you mentioned I also thought about having the Tuple, the separate object or the Lookup structure. I am just not sure which approach would be the best

Comment: i don't know the context of the program, but potentially a tuple and linq would be the best solution? i have undated my answer for the dictionary with a custom object for you anyway.